# Apex Callout HTTP Version not supported

Tags: http, salesforce, apex

I  am working on deleting the file from the Amazon from sfdc.

I have written the code for it when am sending the request to Amazon  It through error:-

> System.HttpResponse[Status=HTTP Version not supported, StatusCode=505]

kindly help me to solve this problem

How can I overcome this error to pass correct request?

Code:

```
Datetime expire = system.now().addDays(1);
String dateString = expire.formatGmt('yyyy-MM-dd')+'T'+ expire.formatGmt('HH:mm:ss')+'.'+expire.formatGMT('SSS')+'Z';
String stringToSign =   'DELETE\n' +
                        '\n' +
                        '\n' +
                        dateString + '\n' +
                        ('https://s3.amazonaws.com/'+awsKeySet[0].Name__c+'/'+fname).replaceAll(' ', '');

stringToSign = stringToSign.replaceAll(' ', '%20');
System.debug('FINDME::stringToSign - ' + stringToSign);
Blob mac = Crypto.generateMac('HMacSHA1',Blob.valueOf(stringToSign), Blob.valueOf(+awsKeySet[0].AWS_Secret_Key__c));
stringToSign = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(mac);

//String encoded = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(stringToSign, 'UTF-8');
HttpRequest con = new HttpRequest();
con.setHeader('Authorization',+awsKeySet[0].AWS_AccessKey_Id__c+':' + stringToSign);
con.setEndPoint('https://s3.amazonaws.com/'+awsKeySet[0].Name__c+'/'+'Temporary/'+fname);
con.setHeader('Host',+awsKeySet[0].Name__c+'.s3.amazonaws.com');
//con.setHeader('Date', dateString);
con.setMethod('DELETE');
Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(con);
System.debug('RES.GETBODY: ' + res.getBody() + ' RES.GETSTATUS: ' + res.getStatus() + ' CON.GETENDPT: ' + con.getEndPoint());
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem typically arises from an invalid URL in the HTTP request as can be seen in this [post](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gwVKAAY) in Salesforce success community and this [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/79169/how-to-resolve-http-version-not-supported-or-statuscode-505-error) in Salesforce StackExchange. This line here is where I would start:

```
con.setEndPoint('https://s3.amazonaws.com/'+awsKeySet[0].Name__c+'/'+'Temporary/'+fname);
```

There are references to an sobject field `awsKeySet[0].Name__c` and a variable `fname` that you resolve into your URL string.

Are you certain there are no spaces or unescaped characters in the underlying value of either of those?